# Nested fragments no view found for list fragment item

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have nested fragments. I have activity A that has fragment B which has List fragment, when user clicks item from ListFragment I want to open new fragment using onListItemClick method.
But I am getting no view found for id error.

Code looks like this:

```
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList warnings;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        warnings = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            warnings.add(i);
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, warnings);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_other, container, false);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

   }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         ListItemFragment listItemFragment = new ListItemFragment();

        FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, listItemFragment);
        ft.attach(listItemFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    }
```

it doesn't seem to like android.R.id.tabcontent.

I have other child fragments working fine.

Please help.

Comment: Post the error from logcat please.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x1020011 (android:id/tabcontent) for fragment ListItemFragment{41e65368 #0 id=0x1020011}

Comment: is it enough to figure out problem, I am not able to paste whole error log here.

Comment: That is fine. Please post the code that opens Fragment B and the code that shows the ListFragment in Fragment B.

Comment: Fragment B:public void pushFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment1, Fragment fragment2){
        FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

        ft.detach(fragment1).replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment2);
        ft.attach(fragment2).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

Comment: ListFragment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listfragment, container, false);

        return view;
    }

Comment: Code that shows the list fragment in fragment B is in the question. My second code is just a fragment that i wanted to show after clicking item, that code you can see in the question again.

Comment: Please update the question with the code. Don't post it here in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you nesting the fragments in xml?  You can only add nested fragments programmatically.  See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

Comment: No I am not nesting fragments in xml I am doing programmatically.Let me update the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having, I was trying to attach fragment when I am already in fragment.

This should be done by detaching current fragment and attaching another one.

Now my app works just fine.

Something like this:

```
ft.detach(getParentFragment()).replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
ft.attach(fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```